# Network Images not showing in android Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, image, api, mobile

I am working on a recipe searching flutter app for android. I am using [Edamam API](https://developer.edamam.com/). I am also using a dummy image of the user for now (because I haven't connected my application with Firebase so far). The images are loaded in the android emulator, but it doesn't load any photos when I run the app on my actual phone. Please have a look at my problem.

Emulator's Screenshot: [image: Cookpad Emulator Screenshot]
Actual Phone's Screenshot: [image: Cookpad Mobile Screenshot]

This is the code for loading images from API.

```
image: DecorationImage(
                  image:
                      NetworkImage(query["hits"][index]["recipe"]["image"]),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the AndroidManifest.xml file located at ./android/app/src/main

```
      <manifest>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
      <application>
```

i guess you didn't add internet permission in you menifest.xml

Comment: There are lots of AndroidManifest.xml files. Which one should I edit? And where should I add this internet permission?

Comment: I have updated the answer in your project \android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml and add permission below manifest tag and above application tag as edited in my answer

Comment: Still the data called from API is not showing in my phone.

Comment: I have added another permission in my answer add that as well and build release again hopefully this will make it done

Answer (score 0):

I guess either image is not available on the server due to path changed or deleted from server else image value receive `null`.

I faced similar issue many times.
please check once.

thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually, API Call was taking time and the variable storing the data was null. That's why it was not showing any data.